# How do i detect the collision or trigger when object is picked through mouse click with raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision-detection, collision

If we picked the gameobject with `OnMouseDown()` method the default `OnCollisionEnter2D()` or `OnTriggerEnter2D()` methods work. But if we picked the gameobject with raycast how do we detect the collision or trigger with other gameobject?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way described in Unity Docs. Try here: [Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html)

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your answer, rather than only including a link - otherwise, in the event that the link breaks due to updates to the documentation (eg. When a new version of Unity is released), your answer becomes basically useless.

Comment: It doesn't have right answer. If i have one object in the mouse position if that object contact with any other object i need to do some operation...